# Why doesn't Hibernate batch inserts of fields annotated with @ElementCollection?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-boot-jpa

I have an `@Entity` containing a few `@OneToMany` relationships, but since they consist of collections of `Enum`s, I'm using `@ElementCollection`. The entity has an id that gets generated at the database level (MySQL).

Here is a small example I just made up that corresponds to the structure of my entity.

```java
@Entity
public class Student {

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @ElementCollection(targetClass = Language.class)
  @CollectionTable(name="student_languages", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="student_id"))
  private Set<Language> languages;

  @ElementCollection(targetClass = Module.class)
  @CollectionTable(name="student_modules", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="student_id"))
  private Set<Module> modules;

  @ElementCollection(targetClass = SeatPreference.class)
  @CollectionTable(name="student_seats", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="student_id"))
  private Set<SeatPreference> seatPreference;

[...]
}
```

I know that `GenerationType.IDENTITY` deactivates batching, but I thought that would be the case **for the main entity only**, not for the single properties too. I'm havin to bulk import a few entities (~20k), each with a handful of properties, but Hibernate seems to be generating one insert for each property in the sets, making the import impossibly slow (between 10 and 20 inserts for each record).

I have now spent so long trying to make this faster, that I'm considering just generating an SQL file that I can manually import in the database.

Is there no way to instruct Hibernate to batch inserts the `@ElementCollection` fields? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A suggestion from experience: don't bother with Hibernate for performant inserts and auto-ids, but use something more low level like [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#jdbc-advanced-jdbc) or [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/). You will save yourself many wasted hours.

Comment: Did you try the following properties in your hibernate.cfg.xml file:

hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5
hibernate.order_inserts=true

Other trick that you could apply, define a batch size app.properties and iterate your collection if it reaches to the batch size flush hibernate session.

Comment: It batches with the latest MariaDB. I'll test with MySQL shortly.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, seem hibernate will not help with `@ElementCollection`  batching but you can use the SQL [bulk inserts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)#Multirow_inserts).
Seems you are on MySQL which does support the bulk inserts and its JDBC driver can automatically modify / rewrite the individual insert statements into one bulk statement if you enable the  `rewriteBatchedStatements` property.

So in your case what you need to do is tell hibernate to enable batching and order the batch inserts and updates.

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
hibernate.order_inserts=true
hibernate.order_updates=true
```

This will ensure that when inserting the data into DB the inserts statements generated by Hibernate will be executed in a batch and they will be ordered.

So the SQL generated by Hibernate will be something like this:

```
insert into student_languages (student_id, languages) values (1,1)
insert into student_languages (student_id, languages) values (1,2)
insert into student_languages (student_id, languages) values (1,3)
insert into student_languages (student_id, languages) values (1,4)
```

Next, you will need to tell the JDBC driver to rewrite the individual inserts into the bulk insert by setting the `rewriteBatchedStatements=true`

```
jdbc:mysql://db:3306/stack?useSSL=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

So this will instruct the driver to rewrite the inserts into bulk form, so the above several SQL statements will be rewritten into something like this

```
insert into student_languages (student_id, languages) values (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)
```

Just as an info this may not work if you are using old versions of the MySQL driver and Hibernate.

Comment: ANSI SQL is an ancient standard. Batch inserts were standardized many years ago.

Comment: @AlexeyVeleshko it would be helpful if you can share the link to the bulk insert SQL standard, so I can update the answer.

Comment: I can't link to the SQL-92 standard itself (they are not freely distributed), but this Wikipedia link should be enough: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)#Multirow_inserts

Comment: Batching also appears to be synonymous with bulk inserts, see https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ where Hibernate is configured for batching and generates bulk inserts without any JDBC driver-specific configuration.

Comment: @nickb yep, but that does not seem to work with ```@ElementCollections```, so you need to rewrite on driver level.

Comment: Right, I think the premise behind the question is *why* doesn't batching work with `@ElementCollection` when it does for inserting top-level entities, and is there a way to get Hibernate to bulk insert `@ElementCollection`. You have found one solution, the MySQL driver configuration `rewriteBatchedStatements`. I also wonder if there is a solution that doesn't depend on which JDBC driver is in use. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer and your research.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this both with MySQL and MariaDB and actually Hibernate does batch inserts into the collection table. But it's not visible to the naked eye, you have to use [DataSource-Proxy](https://vladmihalcea.com/log-sql-spring-boot/) to see it:

```
INFO  com.example.jpa.AddStudents - Adding students
DEBUG n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener - 
Name:dataSource, Connection:3, Time:1, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["insert into student (name) values (?)"]
Params:[(Smith)]
DEBUG n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener - 
Name:dataSource, Connection:3, Time:1, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["insert into student (name) values (?)"]
Params:[(Snow)]
DEBUG n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener - 
Name:dataSource, Connection:3, Time:78, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:True, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:6
Query:["insert into student_languages (student_id, language) values (?, ?)"]
Params:[(6,2),(6,0),(6,1),(7,0),(7,4),(7,3)]
INFO  com.example.jpa.AddStudents - Added
```

The `SEQUENCE` ID generator is [considered](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) the best for Hibernate. It doesn't create lock contention as the `TABLE` generator does and allows for batching. It is unfortunate that MySQL doesn't support sequences still (MariaDB does).

> Am I doing something wrong?

Hibernate is optimized for small-scale changes in the database. It maintains a first-level cache and also supports a second-level cache which will only hinder performance for large-scale operations. Therefore, indeed, you might be better off using JDBC or jOOQ for this particular operation as was suggested in the comments.

---

I used MySQL 8.0.3, MariaDB 10.5.13 and Hibernate 5.6.3.Final.